# chained relationship - Eloquent ORM Laravel

Tags: api, orm, laravel-9

The situation I found is as follows:
I have three tables, stores, cities and states.

store columns - id, cities_id, name ...

city ​​columns - id, states_id, name

states columns - id, name, initials

I'm creating an API, and I want my localhost:8000/v1/api/store endpoint to fetch all store records and bring information about cities and states in the same json, I would like the return json to be:

```
{
   "msg":"Resources found.",
   "data":{
      "id":1,
      "totvs_code":"34",
      "name":"test",
      "cities_id":1400100,
      "address":"tested street",
      "district":"district",
      "zip code":"13348380",
      "active":0,
      "cities":{
         "id":1400100,
         "states_id":14,
         "name":"Boa Vista",
         "States":{
            "id":14,
            "name":"Sao Paulo",
            "initials":"SP"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Currently, the result when accessing the get store endpoint is:

```
{
   "msg":"Resources found.",
   "date":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "totvs_code":"34",
         "name":"test",
         "cities_id":1400100,
         "address":"testeeee street",
         "district":"district",
         "zip_code":"13348380",
         "active":0,
         "cities":{
            "id":1400100,
            "states_id":14,
            "name":"Boa Vista"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I have no idea how to create this relationship in the models and call it in the controller, could you help me? Thank you very much.

**Model Store**

```
class Store extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'totvs_code', 'name', 'cities_id', 'address', 'district', 'zip_code', 'active'];

    public function cities(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Citie'); //PERTENCE A - BelongsTo
    }

}
```

**Model Citie**

```
class Citie extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'states_id', 'name'];

    public function states(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\State', 'states_id');
    }
}
```

**Model State**

```
class State extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'initials'];
}
```

**StoreController - index get all **

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $storeRepository = new StoreRepository($this->store);

         //query está sendo montada
        if($request->has('atributos_cidade')) { //selecionar atributos específico de reward_group / relacionamento
            $atributos_cidade = 'cities:id,' . $request->atributos_cidade;
            $storeRepository->selectRelationshipAttributes($atributos_cidade);
        } else {
            $storeRepository->selectRelationshipAttributes('cities');
        };

        //query está sendo montada
        if ($request->has('filtro')) {
            $storeRepository->filter($request->filtro);
        }


        //query está sendo montada
        if ($request->has('atributos')) {
            $storeRepository->selectAttributes($request->atributos);
        }

        //query montada, get será realizado.
        return response()->json([
            'msg' => 'Recursos encontrados.',
            'data' => $storeRepository->getResults()
        ], 200);
    }
```

**Store Controller - show get especific**

```
/**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Store  $store
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    
public function show($id)
    {
        $store = $this->store->find($id);

        if ($store == null) {
            return response()->json([
                'msg' => 'Recurso pesquisado não existe.'
            ],
            404);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'msg' => 'Recurso encontrado.',
            'data' => $store
        ], 200);
    }
```

**Designer Patterns - Repositories>AbstractRepository**

```
abstract class AbstractRepository{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function selectRelationshipAttributes($attributes){
        $this->model = $this->model->with($attributes);
        //a query está sendo montada
    }

    public function filter($filters){
        $filters = explode(';', $filters);

        foreach($filters as $key => $condition) {
            $c = explode(':', $condition);

            //$c[0] - coluna
            //$c[1] - condição
            //$c[2] - valor
            $this->model = $this->model->where($c[0], $c[1], $c[2]);
        }
        //a query está sendo montada
    }

    public function selectAttributes($attributes){
        $this->model = $this->model->selectRaw($attributes);

        //a query está sendo montada
    }


    //a query foi montada, basta realizar o select no banco.
    public function getResults(){
        return $this->model->get();

    }

}
```

**StoreRepository**

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

class StoreRepository extends AbstractRepository{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting for someone's answer, I did a little more in-depth research and found that to do these nesting just type the methods inside "with", separating them with ".", see an example below:

$shop = $this->shop->with('cities.states')->find($id);

That way my return json came exactly as needed:

```
{
   "msg":"Recurso encontrado.",
   "data":{
      "id":1,
      "totvs_code":"34",
      "name":"teste",
      "cities_id":1400100,
      "address":"testeeee rua",
      "district":"bairro",
      "zip_code":"13348380",
      "active":0,
      "cities":{
         "id":1400100,
         "states_id":14,
         "name":"Boa Vista",
         "states":{
            "id":14,
            "name":"Roraima",
            "initials":"RR"
         }
      }
   }
```